# How to assign the success/fail status of a function to a variable in Bash?

Tags: bash, variable, function, exit-status

I know that a way to do it is :

```
# run a command here, like [[ $A == *"ABC"* ]]
result=$?
if (( result == 0 ))
then
  result=true
else
  result=false
fi
```

Then I can do :

```
if $result
then
...
```

Is there a one line way to write the first block of code? I can do something like this in C :

```
bool result = funct_a() && funk_b()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
cmd && result=true || result=false
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you'd put the command directly in the `if` statement, instead of going around `$?` and `(( .. ))`. Especially with something like `[[ .. ]]`: it's even made to look like a conditional structure.

```
if [[ $A == *"ABC"* ]]; then
     result=true
     dosomethinghere
     ...
```

Also, do note that if you run `if $result ...`, you're actually running the command contained in the variable `result`. `true` and `false` are fine to run as commands, but you wouldn't want to do that if `result` could contain something like `rm`...

Instead you could just save the value of `$?` as you did above, with `result=$?` and then use `if (( result == 0 ))` or `if [[ $result == 0 ]]` when you need to, instead of adding another level of assignments to `result`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
cmd; f result
```

with help of this little function:

```
f () { last="$?"; declare -n ref="$1"; [[ "$last" == 0 ]] && ref=true || ref=false;}
```

(You could call this function something more suitable than just `f`... I don't know what's more suitable.) Anyhow, it has have to be applied immediately after the command and separated from the command with a semicolon, not chained with `&&` or `||`. It takes the name of a the result variable without the `$`. The function makes a reference of the name passed and the rest is obvious.

Here's a demonstration:

```
$ f () { last="$?"; declare -n ref="$1"; [[ "$last" == 0 ]] && ref=true || ref=false;}
$ true; f result; echo "$result"
true
$ false; f result; echo "$result"
false
```

You might also go for a still more sophisticated helper:

```
g () { declare -n ref="$1"; shift; "$@" && ref=true || ref=false; }
```

This one is supposed to be provide with the result variable followed by the command. The rest is the same. Here's `g` in action:

```
$ g () { declare -n ref="$1"; shift; "$@" && ref=true || ref=false; }
$ g result ls -lt; echo "$result"
total 2488
drwxr-xr-x  6 tomas tomas    4096 Jan 22 11:41 Documents
drwxr-xr-x  2 tomas tomas    4096 Jan 22 11:26 Pictures
...
true
$ g result asdfasdf; echo "$result"
bash: asdfasdf: command not found
false
```

Or you can keep the names `f` and `g` if you like.